# Null-operator confusion

Tags: c#

I'm having the following code from an article which I quite don't understand the difference in them regarding the use of null-operators:

```
if (memberAccessExpr?.Name.ToString() != "Match") return;
```

This one is clear to me I guess, checking the `memberAccessExpr` for null, and if it is null, the comparison with "Match" return false, is that correct?

The confusion comes with the second one:

```
if (memberSymbol?.ToString().StartsWith("System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match") ?? true) return;
```

This line of code seems to me is pretty much the same as the first, since I do a simple null check and then call a function which returns a boolean value (`!=` vs. `StartsWith`)...So why do I need an additional ??-operator here, and not in the first line? Maybe it has something to do with the implicit `== true` comparison that would take place without the ??-operator?

I have no clue, so maybe you guys can enlighten me : )

Cheers,
Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The null propagation operator returns `null` if the left-part is `null`, or the right part if it's not. If the right part would return a value type, it gets converted to a `Nullable<T>`... so if the right part would return a `bool`, if there's a `?.` it will return a `Nullable<bool>` (or `bool?`).

So for the first:

```
if (memberAccessExpr?.Name.ToString() != "Match") return;
```

Means roughly (verbose on purpose):

```
string comparer;

if(memberAccessExpr == null) 
  comparer = null;
else
  comparer = memberAccessExpr.Name.ToString();

if(comparer != "Match") return;
```

For the second:

```
if (memberSymbol?.ToString().StartsWith("System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match") ?? true) return;
```

Means roughly:

```
bool? comparer;

if (memberSymbol == null)
  comparer = null;
else
  comparer = memberSymbol.ToString().StartsWith("System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match");

if(comparer ?? true) return;
```

If the last line confuses you, the `??` operator means roughly: "if the left part is null, return right part, else return left part"

Comment: okay now I get it, since the expression in the second line is a nullable bool..confusing stuff..but thanks for the good answer : )

Comment: it becomes a nullable bool since you are using the `?.` operator, so it needs to be able to hold both a `null` value and the result of the right-hand expression (which is a `bool`), thus, `bool?`. Note that the code is not what the compiler does, it's what I wrote to explain to you

Comment: so basically if a call anything on an object with ?. operator that returns simple types, I can check the result with an ?? operator since it becomes the nullable of type, right?

Comment: That is right :-) (you mean `value` types, not `simple` types, but yes)

Comment: great, now I totally get it, thank you very much for the help : )

Comment: I'll add a note on the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You have some shorthand operators concerning `?` and `??`

[?. Operator MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx)

```
int? length = customers?.Length; // null if customers is null 
Customer first = customers?[0];  // null if customers is null
int? count = customers?[0]?.Orders?.Count();  // null if customers, the first customer, or Orders is null
```

[?? Operator MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

```
// Assign i to return value of the method if the method's result
// is NOT null; otherwise, if the result is null, set i to the
// default value of int.
int i = GetNullableInt() ?? default(int);
```

[?: Operator MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

```
// if-else construction.
if (input > 0)
    classify = "positive";
else
    classify = "negative";

// ?: conditional operator.
classify = (input > 0) ? "positive" : "negative";
```